# How to know which TextFormField the user is focusing on?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This is an example of the code I made, it has to be processed manually, I find it very long

```
class _TestNodeState extends State<TestNode> {
  final _focusNode1 = FocusNode();
  final _focusNode2 = FocusNode();
  final _focusNode3 = FocusNode();
  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusNode1.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode1.hasFocus) {
        //Processing code for this focus node
      }
    });
    _focusNode2.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode2.hasFocus) {
        //Processing code for this focus node
      }
    });
    _focusNode3.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode3.hasFocus) {
        //Processing code for this focus node
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          focusNode: _focusNode1,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          focusNode: _focusNode2,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          focusNode: _focusNode3,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I want to ask if there is another, more concise way to manage these focusNodes and know which `TextFormField` the user focuses on.

Comment: create a class that has both `FocusNode focusNode` and the `_listener` callback and just call `focusNode.addLustener(_listener)` inside the constructor

Comment: @pskink Can you be more specific?

Comment: `class MyFocusNode extends FocusNode {
MyFocusNode(this.i, this.notifier) {
addListener(_listener);
}

final int i;
final ValueNotifier<int> notifier;

void _listener() {
if (hasFocus) notifier.value = i;
}
}
` and you create it like `MyFocusNode(0, notifier)`, `MyFocusNode(1, notifier)` etc and each time you change the focus `notifier` will be notified with 0, 1 etc

Comment: btw you can also use it directly: `TextFormField(focusNode: MyFocusNode(0, notifier))`, `TextFormField(focusNode: MyFocusNode(1, notifier)),` etc